# VBA Code for Excel master sheet template produces error "Method "Range" of object "_Worksheet" failed"

Tags: excel, vba

so this is my code:

```
Sub Mirror_Master_Plus1()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim x As Long

    Sheets("Master").Select
    For x = 1 To 10
    Range("Master!A1:C" & 9 + x).Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

What I want to do is have an excel master sheet template that automatically copies the layout (data, rows and columns) to other sheets in the same file when changed. But I get this error...

Am fairly new to VBA.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Please, replace `Range("Master!A1:C" & 9 + x)` with only `Range("A1:C" & 9 + x)`... But a better idea should be to fully qualify the range in a different way, `Dim shM as Worksheet` then `Set shM = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Master")` and use it as  `shM.Range("A1:C" & 9 + x)`.

Comment: Thanks! The answer below made it work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made minor modification of your code itself. Please try.

You don't have to use Range("Master!A1:C" & 9 + x). Use instead Range("A1:C" & (9 + x)). Also avoid the use of 'Select' in the code whenever possible.

```
Sub Mirror_Master_Plus1()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
        Dim x As Long, ws As Worksheet

        Set ws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Master"))
        
            For x = 1 To 10
            
                Sheets("Master").Range("A1:C" & (9 + x)).Copy ws.Range("A1")
            
            Next
            
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Why the loop and not just  `Sheets("Master").Range("A1:C19")).Copy ws.Range("A1")`